# Accessing Google Group archive without receiving group emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-groups

I have had a Gmail account, but don't want to receive emails there any longer. I signed up for a Google Group with a non-Gmail address. This prevents me from accessing the group archives. How do I use my Gmail address to access the group archive, without receiving group emails in my Gmail?

Comment: Thanks Ruben but that was not my problem. I am in a google group, but my google account shows I am in no groups. So I can't access the archives of the group I'm in. The moderator signed me up with a non-google email address. I have several gmail addresses. So I asked him to add one of my gmail address and will see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

From [Leave a group or unsubscribe from emails](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/46608?hl=en)

> **Unsubscribe from a group**
> You can stop getting emails from a group by changing your settings or leaving the group.
>
> 1. Sign in to [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/).
> 2. Locate the group you want and then choose an option:
>
> - To stay in the group but stop getting emails, under **Subscription**, click the displayed option and then select **No email**.